# Plugin: How to Validate Array field in editableTableField?

Tags: plugin-development

In my template I defined field as:

```
{{ forms.editableTableField({
  id: 'songs',
  name: 'songs',
  cols: [
    {
      heading: 'Time',
      type: 'select',
      options: [
        {'label':'00:00','value':'00:00'},
        {'label':'00:30','value':'00:30'},
        {'label':'01:00','value':'01:00'},
        {'label':'01:30','value':'01:30'},
        {'label':'02:00','value':'02:00'},
        {'label':'02:30','value':'02:30'},
        {'label':'03:00','value':'03:00'},
        {'label':'03:30','value':'03:30'},
        {'label':'04:00','value':'04:30'},
        {'label':'05:00','value':'05:30'},
        {'label':'06:00','value':'06:30'},
        {'label':'07:00','value':'07:30'}
      ]
    },
    {
      heading: 'SoundCloud URL',
      type: 'singleline'
    }
  ]
}) }}
```

How do I add validation rules in model? This does not work:

```
return array(
    'songs[][]' => array(AttributeType::String, 'label' => 'Sound Cloud Track URL','required'  => true),
    'scheduledTime' => AttributeType::DateTime
);
```

In controller I am doing:

```
$songs = new PlugInName_ControllerModel();

if($songs->validate()) {
    echo 'Hurray';
} else {
    echo 'Epic Fail';
}
```